# Internet censored (Kazakhstan)

Tags: tor-browser-bundle, anonymity

I downloaded tor browser then all its folder to connect local proxy settings SERVIR for internet access questions had no answers' cause I don `t know the ip address and port, and proxy type. In short one I pomozher pozhalusta

Answer (score 5):

[image: Pluggable Transports Infographic]

Use [Pluggable Transports](https://www.torproject.org/docs/pluggable-transports.html.en#user).

1. Choose Configure (or accessed under the Green Onion Menu -> Tor Network Settings)
2. Choose 'My ISP block connections...'.
3. Choose `obfs4`, `meek-azure` or `meek-amazon`.
4. Select Okay.

Unless you normally need to configure a proxy to connect to the internet, do not choose to use a proxy.

Answer (score 0):

You need to get a bridges as it's said on https://www.torproject.org/docs/bridges and put them into your config.

Feel free to ask further questions - and you can ask me in russian too =)

Answer (score 0):

Use Pluggable Transport `scramblesuit`: go to [Tor bridges](https://bridges.torproject.org/), and, when asked, choose Pluggable Transport `scramblesuit`. Get those lines and paste them to the Tor Browser's `Enter custom bridges` text field.

---

That's the only way I've got it working recently with Tor Browser 6.5.1 and Beeline KZ provider. The simplier ways: selecting any of the preconfigured transport types `fte`, `meek-azure`, `meek-amazon`, `obfs`, `obfs4` in the Tor Network Settings didn't work (`no connection` or was stuck at connect).